# SSRS Subscriptions showing status success but not triggering e-mails

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have come across the issue with SSRS data driven subscription where the status of the subscription is showing 70 processed of 70 but no e-mails are triggered.The subscriptions are being successfully run since long time and I face this issue today.

To give some more info the reports are hosted on a sharepoint.

Comment: How do you know no emails are triggered?

Comment: This usually means that the report ran fine, but the emails weren't delivered. Check your SMTP settings. Check the inbox of the account you're using to send these through to see if you're getting undeliverable messages for example.